# Using an Object's postion for an Event in AFrame

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I'm trying to make a component that checks the current position of a sphere in an AFrame scene and when it hits a specific coordinate and when it does it fires an event (In example below it resets it to its default position):

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent("trackball", {
  update: function() {
    let pos = this.el.getAttribute("position");
    if (pos == {x:-21.821,y: 1,z: 0})
      {
        this.el.setAttribute("position", "-21.821 5 0");
      }
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what format is returned when `.getAttribute("position")` is called so that may be why it's not working. I am running AFrame 1.1.0.

Comment: It may be hard to detect using a specific point, I'd rather try doing `pos.y < 1 && pos.z < -21.821`

Comment: Oh, use a range like ```(pos.x > -23  && pos.x < -20)&&(pos.y > 0 && pos.y < 2)&&(pos.z > -1 && pos.z < 2)```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `update` is called when attributes are changed via `setAttribute()`. If you want a function that is called on each render frame, then use `tick()`.

Secondly, try using a range, instead of a fixed point, it's very likely that the object will move past the point between two ticks.

Something like this:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/n5ro/aframe-physics-system@v4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent("trackball", {
  tick: function() {
    let pos = this.el.getAttribute("position");
    if (pos.y < 0.5) {
        // reset position
        this.el.setAttribute("position", "0 3 -4")
        // sync
        this.el.components["dynamic-body"].syncToPhysics();
      }
  }
});
</script>
<a-scene physics cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="0.25" color="#EF2D5E" dynamic-body trackball></a-sphere>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" static-body></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Also try using the `object3D` properties instead `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` when dealing with frequently called functions (which certainly applies to `tick()`):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/n5ro/aframe-physics-system@v4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("trackball", {
    // iife to initialize the "origin point" once
    tick: (function() {
      const origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 3, -4);
      const y_range = 0.5;
      return function() {
        // check if the ball is out of range
        const pos = this.el.object3D.position
        if (pos.y < y_range) {
          // reset position
          pos.copy(origin);
          // sync
          this.el.components["dynamic-body"].syncToPhysics();
        }
      }
    })()
  });
</script>
<a-scene physics cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -4" radius="0.25" color="#EF2D5E" dynamic-body trackball></a-sphere>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" static-body></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Keep in mind, updating the position in such manner is more performant, but will cause `getAttribute("position")` to return the last position set via `setAttribute("position", new_position)`

Comment: Yes. I was about to post this as the answer. I didn't realize that ```update``` only fired when ```.setAttribute()``` is called. It works now. That is exactly how my code looks as well

Comment: @ProtocolAlpha one more thing came to my mind - check out the edit

Comment: I was never good at three.js code. So I went with the AFrame code.

Comment: @ProtocolAlpha sooner or later it may become necessary, it just came to my mind because it's mentioned in the [docs, in the best practices section](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/best-practices.html#tick-handlers)